# dotnet-core could not found base Interface method

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm facing really odd situation, if i tried in VS 2015 it navigates base symbol method without any problem.Even VS Code with Omnisharp on Ubuntu 16.04 has no problem to navigate to method. But when i run, it simply throws some odd exception. I'm %100 sure method is there...

Here is dotPeek Screenshot for /Yakari.Tests/{outputdir}/Yakari.dll

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the structure:

```
public interface ICacheProvider : IDisposable
{
    .....
    void Set(string key, object value, TimeSpan expiresIn, bool isManagerCall = false);
    .....
}


public interface ILocalCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
{
    ....
}


public abstract class BaseCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
{
    .....
    public abstract void Set(string key, object value, TimeSpan expiresIn, bool isManagerCall = false);
    .....
}


public class LittleThunder : BaseCacheProvider, ILocalCacheProvider
{
    .....
    public override void Set(string key, object value, TimeSpan expiresIn, bool isManagerCall = false)
    {
        ....
    }
    .....   
}
```

When we do something like this:

```
public class SomeTestClass {

    ILocalCacheProvider _localCacheProvider;

    public SomeTestClass(ILocalCacheProvider localCacheProvider) {
        _localCacheProvider = localCacheProvider;
    }

    public void SomeTestMethod() {
        // Below line throws: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException : 'Yakari.ILocalCacheProvider' does not contain a definition for 'Set'
        _localCacheProvider.Set("key", dynamic value, CacheTime.FifteenMinutes);
    }
}
```

Code taken from https://github.com/TitaniumSoft/yakari

**Note:** You can see same runtime error at appveyor [CI Log](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/efaruk/yakari/build/106)

Any ideas ?
Thanks and regards...

Comment: I have created issue(bug): https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/8126

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP didn't provide full details to solve the issue, but OP wants everyone to clone a Git repository that may be not available in the future.

Comment: I have edited following line _localCacheProvider.Set("key", dynamic value, CacheTime.FifteenMinutes);
    } But if you are not still happy, no body is stopping you. But I'think you should be more humble ;)

Comment: And as a reminder: You are not trying to punish me, you are trying to punish the community. You can't punish me, i have already solved my problem and i really don't care reputation points like you. Also I think you are acting selfish...

Comment: At the end of the day, I'm not the StackOverflow Rules Sentinel, but IMHO, if you come here just to solve your issue and you don't care about the content you publish anymore, you're against the spirit of this site and even any collaborative site.

Comment: I don't see how I punish the community when I suggested you that your question should provide as self-contained info as possible and don't redirect anyone to an external source which can go down some day.

Comment: Hopefully next time you'll provide the code to reproduce your issue from scratch and someone like me won't lose his/her time trying to guess information...

Comment: Right now there is enough information to solve the issue, if you have enough knowledge. So of course i care about community, a lot. The issue we are talking about in a project which is open source. I have the spirit bro, don't think so much, you could develop cancer ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128792/discussion-between-efaruk-and-matias-fidemraizer).

Comment: It's not about this. And you added the required info in your question once it has been already answered... I see how all your comments are about invalidating me as person. In the other hand, do you really think that open sourcing is assisting the community? Or what's worse... When a visitor comes to SO and checks a solution, does he/she care about who's the OP and what does it do who knows where? We seek for solutions and good questions, and yours wasn't under the umbrella of how to ask a question in SO.

Comment: Anyway, if you wouldn't lie everyone including a non dynamic methods signature.... Me and e even others world answer what the answerer did exploring your code from an external source

Comment: Anyway good luck and if what I do is software cancer, I'm proud of being the cancer of bad practices!

Comment: I have just invited you to chat. But your ego not allowing you to do so. You are talking about; I have added info after i have got the answer. But you are still down voting for removal. This is not something intimate and you are conflicting your self. Thank you for every thing and i'm done with it...

Comment: Lol how wrong you're... I'm not ready to chat now because I'm at work. And today, until tonight I won't be able to have a chat!

Comment: And I'm not voting for removal, I voted to close the question until you would  change your mind about including as much info in your question instead of redirecting us to an external resource. Now I see that you've rephrased it! And I've retracted my close vote ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting in GreatEagle.cs:line 201 is because you're making an interface call with something typed as "dynamic" passed as a parameter. If a "dynamic" variable is involved, interface dispatch becomes very complicated, reflection-based, and slow.

So for InMemoryCacheItem.ValueObject: why is the property typed as "dynamic"? From a brief search in your repo, you might as well type it as "object" and avoid all the RuntimeBinder pains since you're casting it everywhere anyway. Or at least do a cast to object before you pass it to Set().

Comment: @efaruk BTW this answerer found what's behind your issue by chance. Why you didn't mention you're using dynamic typing??

Comment: @efaruk Now I've deleted my answer. BTW, with your question info it would be easier to think what I answered you some days ago.

Comment: @efaruk Oh yes now I realized that I would need to download your code to firgure this out... As I said in some comment some days ago, this isn't how SO works, because you know that Q&As aren't just there to solve your issues but to be useful for future readers, and what would happen if you drop your GitHub repo?

Comment: If you was try to solve this one out, you were could paste InMemoryCacheItem.cs with your answer. But no problem my friend. Thank you anyway...